# PHP array associative

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Whats the easiest way to convert array a to b

```
a= [['x'=>'a'], ['y'=>'b']] 


b= ['x'=>'a', 'y'=>'b']
```

a and b are just two examples.

Comment: `$b = array_merge (...$a);`

Comment: A more simple solution using **RecursiveIteratorIterator** is present here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: @meagar how is this question a duplicate? Similar solutions don't mean that it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Using array_walk_recursive for arbitrary depth:

```
$b = [];
array_walk_recursive($a, function ($v, $k) use (&$b) { $new[$k] = $v; });
```

Using @splash58 trick with the spread operator if you have only one level deep:

```
$b = array_merge(...$a);
```